# Discord.net 1.0 - How to get Messages to delete?

Tags: c#, discord.net

so I am having problems with my command. It doesn't seem to show any problems, but when I go to use the command i get this back from my bot.

"ERROR:  The input text has too few parameters."

I don't know if I should be using IUserMessage, or SocketMessage, i've tried both and usually get the same error.

I don't know where I went wrong? I have tried to fix this for a while and i'm at a brick wall in trying to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    [Command("purge")]
    [Summary("deletes set amount of text")]
    [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.Administrator)]
    [RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.Administrator)]
    public async Task PurgeChat(IUserMessage msg, int amount)
    {
        int messagesDeleted = 0;
        var purgeMessage = await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync("_purging in progress, give me a minute.._");
        var lastMessageID = purgeMessage.Id;


        try
        {
            var stop = false;
            while (amount > messagesDeleted)
            {
                var messages = await msg.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(lastMessageID, Direction.Before, 15).OfType<IUserMessage>().ToList();
                foreach (IUserMessage message in messages)
                {
                    await message.DeleteAsync();
                    messagesToDelete++;
                    if (messagesDeleted >= amount || messages.Count == 0)
                    {
                        stop = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    lastMessageID = messages.Last().Id;
                }
                if (stop || messages.Count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message != "The server responded with error 404 (NotFound): \"Unknown Message\"")
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Something fucked up while trying to delete messages, you are going to have to manually Delete them for now. or try again");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            await purgeMessage.ModifyAsync(x => x.Content = "_Purge Completed, this message will self destruct in 5 seconds_");
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
             {
                 await Task.Delay(5000);
                 await purgeMessage.DeleteAsync();
             });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[Command("purge", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
[Summary("Deletes the specified amount of messages.")]
[RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.Administrator)]
[RequireBotPermission(ChannelPermission.ManageMessages)]
public async Task PurgeChat(uint amount)
{
    var messages = await this.Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync((int)amount + 1).Flatten();

    await this.Context.Channel.DeleteMessagesAsync(messages);
    const int delay = 5000;
    var m = await this.ReplyAsync($"Purge completed. _This message will be deleted in {delay / 1000} seconds._");
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    await m.DeleteAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are 3 important points for future readers benefit:

1) Deleting *many* messages individually in a loop will cause a very unpleasant rate limit exception.

```
var messages = await msg.Channel.GetMessagesAsync();
foreach (IUserMessage message in messages)
{
     await message.DeleteAsync(); //rate limit exception if too many messages!!!
}
```

2) **BULK Delete:** You want to use the DeleteMessagesAsync() method that BBell gave in his answer to delete **BULK** messages.  However it recently moved into ITextChannel. Here is an example how to use it now:

```
var messages = await msg.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(100).FlattenAsync(); //defualt is 100
await (Context.Channel as SocketTextChannel).DeleteMessagesAsync(messages);
```

Here is another example to access ITextChannel without a cast. Notice the difference?:

```
Context.Guild.GetTextChannel(id);  //yes, because it implements ITextChannel!
Context.Guild.GetChannel(id);   //no, cant delete messages.
```

This fooled me for a while.

3) Discord will not let you delete messages older than 2 weeks with DeleteMessagesAsync().  You will have to do each one manually with message.DeleteAsync().

I sincerely hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem. You took in an IUserMessage called *msg* as a parameter rather than just declaring it later. This expects the command to have an extra input that wouldn't really make sense for a purge command. Here's what I have:

```
    [Command("purge")]
    [Name("purge <amount>")]
    [Summary("Deletes a specified amount of messages")]
    [RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.ManageMessages)]
    [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.ManageMessages)]
    public async Task DelMesAsync(int delnum)
    {
        var items = await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(delnum + 1).Flatten();
        await Context.Channel.DeleteMessagesAsync(items);
    }
```

I took out all of the messaging parts but this should solve your parameter problem.

Answer (score 1):

My code to delete max messages without blocking threads.

Well, there you just need to get an array of messages and start deleting the message for each `IMessage` element.

```
[Command("clean")]
    public async Task Clean(int max)
    {

        var messages = Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(max).Flatten();
        foreach (var h in  await messages.ToArrayAsync())
        {
            await this.Context.Channel.DeleteMessageAsync(h);
        }
    }
```

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context/explanation to it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.